# Linq to DataTable - Cannot cast DBNull

Tags: c#, linq, casting, dbnull

New to Linq, so apologies if this is basic. This query is throwing up the error {"Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Int64'. Please use a nullable type."} when I enumerate the results.

```
    private void AddLevels(long rootid)
    {
        var results = from row in data.AsEnumerable()
                      where row.Field<long>("ParentID") == rootid
                      select row;

        foreach (DataRow row in results)
        {
            //do stuff
        }

    }
```

The column ParentID does accept nulls - do I need to handle these separately?

**EDIT2:** Actual solution below that still uses Linq.

**EDIT:** I solved this by scrapping Linq and just using a DataTable.Select statement instead. If anyone's got input on the performance difference I'd be interested.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use this line in your query:

```
where row.Field<decimal?>("ParentID") == rootid
```

`decimal?` is syntactic sugar for [`System.Nullable<decimal>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx), which is essentially the same as `decimal`, except that it also allows for `null` values.

`long` is a different type altogether -- it can only represent integers and not decimal values, hence the "Specified cast is not valid" error.

Comment: Donut - thanks. That's changed the error to _Specified cast is not valid._

Comment: @David M -- Hrm, it may not be as simple as this; since there's no implicit conversion from `DBNull` to `long?`.

Comment: @David what type is ParentID in your database?

Comment: @Manatherin in the DataTable it's a System.Decimal; in the source DB (Oracle) it's Number(22,0). The rootid is taken from a non-nullable column, if that's relevant?

Comment: @David M Ah, well that's your problem. Hang on, I'll update my answer

Comment: @David M Updated -- basically, just use `decimal?` instead of `long?`

Comment: @David worth noting with Donuts change that rootid is probably meant to be a decimal type too, assuming it is meant to match against that column

Comment: @Donut - Perfect! Helping me learn C# one StackOverflow answer at a time.

Comment: @Manatherin - yep, I've updated rootid as well. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

long rootid is nullable type? It should be then only it can accept nulls