# Nullable type linq c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

in my database there is some row which is null and how can i use nullable type or how can i skip nullable row in linq? but i prefer to use nullable type rather than skip rows (see image)

[image]

Comment: have you tried b.field<decimal?>

Comment: have you tried `b.Field<decimal?>("FloatingPNL")`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq to DataTable - Cannot cast DBNull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7091379/linq-to-datatable-cannot-cast-dbnull)

Comment: Please don't post images of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cast null to a non nullable type (decimal)

You should update your generic type to a nullable type like the below:

**From**

```
 let floatingPNL1 = b.Field<decimal>("FloatingPNL")
```

**To**

```
 let floatingPNL1 = b.Field<decimal?>("FloatingPNL")
```

Another option would be to use an ORM such as dapper, much easier to use and handles the object mapping for you.

Answer (score 0):

Decimal? should be a nullable type

Answer (score 0):

Use `Nullable<decimal>` instead of `decimal`.
Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/)